# Writing recursive functions - Eloquent JS

Tags: javascript, function, recursion, undefined

I'm trying to write a function that checks if a number "N" is even or odd by subtracting 2 until it gets to 1 or 0. A final value of 0 represents even. The goal here is to use a recursive function to reach the final result, but I'm having some issues where all I have returned are undefined.

This is what I have so far.

```
function isEven(number) {
  function subTwo(number) {
    if (number == 0) {
      return true;
    }
    else if (number == 1) {
      return false;
    }
    else if (number > 0) {
      number -= 2;
      subTwo();
    }
    else {
      console.log("bruh");
    }
  };
};

console.log(isEven(50));
// → true
console.log(isEven(75));
// → false
console.log(isEven(-1));
// → ??
```

Does anyone see what I'm doing wrong or have any advice for me?

Thanks.

**EDIT:**

Thanks for the help guys. It was suggested that I remove subTwo completely and use isEven as the recursive function, and that I had to use `return isEven(number)` within the second if/else statement.

Both of those suggestions together helped the code compile correctly.

Thanks a ton guys, although I'm not sure why I got downvoted lol.

Comment: Your code never checks to see if the number is less than zero.

Comment: Also there's no way that that code actually logs those things. Can you post the real function you're working with?

Comment: I just did some work on the code but I can post what I've got now. I took out the function subTwo. I'm going to try using isEven as the recursive function.

Comment: This *is* the code he's working with, the log results are what he wants, not what he's getting: "all I have returned are undefined." @zharriott if this isn't just an assignment or a thought exercise to practice recursive functions, you should be using modulus to check evenness.  Remember negative numbers are even and odd as well, so using absolute value is a must (see CD..'s answer).  One function is enough unless you need to use closures as well (see bransonl's answer)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you define the function `subTwo` but it's never actually called when `isEven` is called. A simpler version would be to not even have another function and do it all with recursive calls of `isEven`

```
function isEven(number) {
  if (number === 0) {
    return true;
  } else if (number === 1) {
    return false;
  } else {
    return isEven(number - 2)
  }
}
```

**EDIT**

Alternatively, if you really want the additional function, notice that you defined `subTwo` to take in a parameter but you did not pass in the parameter when recursively calling it via `subTwo();`. Also, when you recursively call `subTwo(number)`, make sure you actually have `return subTwo(number)` so the value is returned at each recursive call. Additionally, you need to actually call the function and return the result when `isEven(number)` is called via a `return` statement and wrapping the function in brackets and calling it with `number` or manually calling it using `return subTwo(number)`. See below for an example of how you would return at each stage so it passes it all the back up to the original call of `isEven(number)`:

```
function isEven(number) {
  return (function subTwo(number) {
    if (number === 0) {
      return true;
    }
    else if (number === 1) {
      return false;
    }
    else if (number > 0) {
      number -= 2;
      return subTwo(number);
    }
    else {
      console.log("bruh");
    }
  })(number);
};
```

Comment: Didn't even think of using `isEven` as the recursive function. I'll try that. Thank you for the help! This is my first ever question and I'm amazed at the quick and helpful responses here.

Comment: @zharriott Refer to my edit if you want to keep the additional function.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is here:

```
subTwo();
```

You need to pass the current version of number into it:  `subTwo(number);` and return it.

you could also fix the problem by omitting the parameter in the internal function, like so: `function subTwo(){...}`  The internal function already has access to the parent function's parameter ([closure](http://javascriptissexy.com/understand-javascript-closures-with-ease/)), so you don't need to pass that into the internal one.

also, this is not returning anything, it's just logging.  JavaScript always returns something.  If you don't say return "something", it returns `undefined`.

```
 else {
      console.log("bruh");
    }
```

Personally, I would also rework you code like so:

```
function subTwo(number) {
    if (number > 0) {
      number -= 2;
      subTwo();
    }
    else if (number == 1) {
      return false;
    }
    else if (number == 0) {
      return true;
    }
    else {
      console.log("bruh");
    }
  };
```

The statements are then in descending order, so you can quickly see the progression.  It helps people look and see if anything has been missed.

Answer (score 0):

As was said in the comments you never check for a value less than 0. What happens is when you enter the value -1 is it jumps down to the else part of your code. The part that says "console.log("bruh");" After completing that line the program keeps going and returns... nothing. You dont return anything, hence why you get undefined. You should set up your code to handle the case when a negative number is passed in.